# Not able to access statefulset pod via headless service using fqdn

Tags: kubernetes, dns, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

I have a k8 setup that looks like this

`ingress -> headless service (k8 service with clusterIp: none) -> statefulsets ( 2pods)`

Fqdn looks like this:

```
nslookup my-service
Server:         100.4.0.10
Address:        100.4.0.10#53

Name:   my-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local
Address: 100.2.2.8
Name:   my-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local
Address: 100.1.4.2
```

I am trying to reach one of the pod directly via the service using the following fqdn but not able to do so.

```
curl -I my-pod-0.my-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local:8222
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: my-pod-0.my-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local
```

If I try to hit the service directly then it works correctly (as a loadbalancer)

```
curl -I my-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local:8222
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 31 Jul 2021 21:24:42 GMT
Content-Length: 656
```

If I try to hit the pod directly using it's cluster ip,  it also works fine

```
curl -I 100.2.2.8:8222
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 31 Jul 2021 21:29:22 GMT
Content-Length: 656
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

But my use case requires me to be able to hit the statefulset pod using fqdn i.e `my-pod-0.my-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local` . What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example statefulset called `foo` with image `nginx`:

```
k get statefulsets.apps
NAME   READY   AGE
foo    3/3     8m55s
```

This stateful set created following pods(`foo-0,foo-1,foo-2`):

```
k get pod -o wide
NAME      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP             NODE        NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
busybox   1/1     Running   1          3h47m   10.1.198.71    ps-master   <none>           <none>
foo-0     1/1     Running   0          12m     10.1.198.121   ps-master   <none>           <none>
foo-1     1/1     Running   0          12m     10.1.198.77    ps-master   <none>           <none>
foo-2     1/1     Running   0          12m     10.1.198.111   ps-master   <none>           <none>
```

Now create a headless service(`clusterIP is none`) as follow:(make sure to use correct selector same as your statefulset)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: foo
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: web
  selector:
    app: foo
```

Now, do `nslookup` to see the `dns` resolution working for the service.(Optional step)

```
k exec -it busybox -- nslookup nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
Server:    10.152.183.10
Address 1: 10.152.183.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 1: 10.1.198.77 foo-1.nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 2: 10.1.198.111 foo-2.nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 3: 10.1.198.121 foo-0.nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Now validate that, individual resolution per-pod is working:

```
k exec -it busybox -- nslookup foo-1.nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
Server:    10.152.183.10
Address 1: 10.152.183.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      foo-1.nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 1: 10.1.198.77 foo-1.nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
```

More info: [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id)

Note: In this case OP had incorrect mapping of `headless` service and the `statefulset`, this can be verified with below command:

```
k get statefulsets.apps foo -o jsonpath="{.spec.serviceName}{'\n'}"
nignx
```

Ensure that, the mapping.

Comment: but that defeats my whole use case unfortunately, i only know about the pod names (my-pod-0 , my-pod-1) and there is no way for me to know the ip of the pod. Also, if I know the ip of the pod, I can just access it using ip and not bother with fqdn. there are many articles on internet claiming that I should be able to access, pod using it's name including the official documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id

web-{0..N-1}.nginx.default.svc.cluster.local

Comment: I found the issue.. looks like the serviceName attribute in my statefulset was wrong. Once I corrected it , I was able to resolve using the pod names. I will accept your answer but can you please highlight this information in your answer to make sure someone in future doesn't make this same mistake again.

Comment: I don't get what was wrong and what fixed it for you, I just did the followed the instructions in the documentation and it worked fine for me.  Whole experiment is pasted in the answer as POC.

Comment: as I mentioned the statefulset yaml has a property called serviceName, this value was wrong in my case. Once I fixed the value (to my-service), dns started resolving the fqdn of my-pod-0.my-service.my-namespace.defualt.svc.local

Answer (score 2):

Original answer didn't clarify how OP fixed the issue, the problem was in `serviceName` property under statefulset implementation.